# How to specify denied permission redirect url on Azure App Service Authentication/Authorization

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

I know you can add a post_login_redirect_url to where to redirect upon a successful login with facebook. Like:

> /.auth/login/facebook?post_login_redirect_url=/

But if the user denied and aborts the login, how to specify the redirect url?

Currently if you deny you get redirected to

> /.auth/login/facebook/callback?error=access_denied&error_code=200

Getting a 401 status and a message of "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out and providing the URLs you're seeing. Looks like we aren't properly handling this case. Unfortunately there isn't currently a way to avoid this behavior. I've logged a bug in Azure App Service to handle this case properly.